# WSDL possible to transfer a FILE type?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

A "checkResult" service deployed on a node machine is defined to return the result on the node to a cluster controller that sends the request.The result on node ,which is in the form of file, may vary drastically in length,as is often the case with daily log files.

At first,i thought it might be ok just using a single string to pack the whole content of the file,so i defined

```
checkResult(inType *in,OutType *out)
```

where the OutType* is char*. Then i realized that the string could be in KB length or even more. So i wonder whether it is proper to use string here.

I googled a lot and could not find the max length permitted in wsdl(maybe conflict with the local maxbuffer length as well) and did not find any information about transferring a file type parameter either.

Using struct type may be suggested ,but it could be so nested for the file and difficult to parse when some of the elements inside could be nil and absent.

What'd you do when you need to return a file type result or large amount of data in a webservice?

p.s the server and client both in C.

Answer (score 1):

When transferring a large amount of data in a (SOAP) web service request or response, it is generally better practice to use an attachment mechanism versus including the data as part of the body.  Probably the order for considering attachment mechanism (broadest to narrowest adoption):

- **Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM)** - The newest of these specifications (http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/) which is supported in many of the mainstream languages.
- **SOAP with Attachments** - This specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments) has been around for many years and is supported in several languages but notably not by Microsoft.
- **Direct Internet Message Encapsulation (DIME)** - This specification (http://bgp.potaroo.net/ietf/all-ids/draft-nielsen-dime-02.txt) was pushed by Microsoft and support has been provided in multiple languages/frameworks including java and .NET.

Ideally, you would be able to work with a framework to give you code stub generation directly from a WSDL indicating MTOM-based web service.

The critical parts of such a WSDL document include:

1. MTOM policy declaration
2. Policy application in the binding
3. Placeholder for the reference to the attachment in the types (schema) section

If you are working contract-first and have a WSDL in hand, the example in section 1.2 of this site (http://www.w3.org/Submission/WS-MTOMPolicy/) shows the simple additions to be made to declare and apply the MTOM policy.  Appendix I of the same site shows an example of a schema element which allows a web service client or server to identify a reference to the MTOM attachment.

I have not implemented a web service or client in C, but a brief scan of recently-updated packages revealed gSoap (http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) as a possibility for helping in your endeavors.

Give those documents a look and see if they help to advance your project.